# Determine the sum of three consecutive odd ones

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

> The central term of three consecutive odd ones can be determined, if
> it is known that the sum of these is:
>
> i) At most $75$
>
> ii) At least $63$

My attempt was:

Let a $2n-1$ an odd number, then $(2n-1) + (2n+1) +(2n+3) =6n+3$

Using $i) n \leq12$ Exist infinity odd numbers.

Using $ii) n \geq10$ Exist infinity odd numbers.

Using $i), ii)$ together. $n= \{10,11,12\}$

Since the sum of three consecutive numbers is in the form $6n+3$, the sum must be an odd number, so the unique possible value is $11$. But if $6n+3=11$, $2n+1$ isn't a integer number, therefore i can't assure.

But, my second solution was the same, but let $2n+1$ an odd number, then:

$(2n+1)+(2n+3)+(2n+5)=6n+9$

Using $i) n \leq 11$ Exist infinity odd numbers.

Using $ii) n \geq 9$ Exist infinity odd numbers.

Using both together, $n= \{9,10,11\}$

The sum is of the form $6n+9$, Therefore is an odd sum too.

Then the possible value are $9,11$, But with $6n+9=11$, the central term isn't an integer number, however with $6n+9=9 => n = 0$, thus the central term is $3$ that work with $1+3+5 = 9$. According to the guide, the correct solution is

> Additional information is required

That is according to my first solution, but no with my second solution. What is wrong with my second solution?

Comment: "the sum of three consecutive numbers is in the form 6n+3, the sum must be an odd number"  The sum is $6n+3$.  $6n +3$ is *always* an odd number. "so the unique possible value is 11".  $n$ isnt that sum. $6n+3$ is the sum.  If $n=10,11,12$ then the sum is $6n+3= 63, 69$ or $75$.  "But if 6n+3=11"  $6n+3$ *doesn't* equal $11$. $n$ equals $11$ (or $10$ or $12$).  $6n + 3= 69$ (or $63$ or $75$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, for the consecutive odd terms
$2n-1,$ $2n+1,$ $2n+3,$
you correctly deduce that the sum is $6n+3$ and that $n \in \{10,11,12\}.$

But then you start treating $n$ as if it were the sum.
That is a mistake. The variable $n$ is just some integer that you put into some formulas for convenience. It is not equal to *any* of the numbers of interest in the question:
not the middle term, not either of the other terms, and certainly not the sum.

Note that $6n+3$ is just as odd when $n$ is $10$ or $12$ as it is when $n=11.$
So you have no reason based on "the sum must be odd" to reject any of the three values of $n.$
Likewise you have no reason to take any of the elements of $\{10,11,12\}$
and say it must be equal to $6n+3.$
Again, $n$ is just an arbitrary integer parameter you introduced, and $6n+3$ is the sum, which is something completely different from any possible value of $n.$

You have the same kind of mistake in your second attempt.
You come up with $1 + 3 + 5 = 9,$ but $9$ is not at least $63$ as was required for the sum of the three consecutive odd numbers.
In fact $n = 9$ is a perfectly fine solution, but then the terms are
$$(2n+1)+(2n+3)+(2n+5) = 19+21+23 = 63.$$
On the other hand, $n=10$ and $n=11$ are perfectly fine solutions too when you correctly write out all the formulas. So you cannot conclude that $n=9.$

It is fine to introduce an arbitrary integer variable like $n$ so that you have something to base formulas on, but you must always remember what the variables you introduce are **not** (in this case, not the sum of the three terms).

---

My approach: let $S$ be the sum, $m$ the middle term. We know $m$ is odd and the other two terms are $m - 2$ and $m + 2.$
The sum of the three terms is therefore $3m.$
That gives us $m = S/3.$
Since $63 \leq S \leq 75,$ we have $21 \leq m \leq 25.$
But by inspection, $m = 21,$ $m = 23,$ and $m=25$ all solve the given conditions. That is why more information is required.

Comment: @YiFan That's right, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for good explanation.